# Read in 3 exams.. outputting the student names, their grades, the average, and their letter grade. Nested Loops,

Tags: java, arrays, nested-loops

Everything is computing as it should, all except for the fact that computing the average will only work on the first input (there are 5 student grade inputs, 3 grades each)

I just need help on why it only seems to compute the first grade.

**Example output:**

Jake Smith - Exam Grades: 67 45 32, Average: 48.0, Letter Grade: F

Jerry Jones - Exam Grades: 80 90 100, Average: 90.0, Letter Grade: A

Hanna Davis - Exam Grades: 88 78 85, Average: 83.66666666666667, Letter Grade: B

**My output:**

Jake Smith - Exam Grades: 67 45 32, Average: 48.0, Letter Grade: F

Jerry Jones - Exam Grades: 80 90 100, Average: 138.0, Letter Grade: A

Hanna Davis - Exam Grades: 88 78 85, Average: 221.66666666666666, Letter Grade: A

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentExamAvgLtrGrade {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int ROWS = 5, COLUMNS = 3;
    
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] studentName = { "Jake Smith", "Jerry Jones", "Hanna Davis", "Betty Lewis", "Elle Garcia" };                    
    double[] numericAverage = new double[ROWS];
    char[] gpa = new char[ROWS];
    int[][] studentGrade = new int[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    double total;
    total = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
          studentGrade[i][j] = scnr.nextInt();
          total += studentGrade[i][j];
       }
       numericAverage[i] = total / studentGrade[i].length; //its something about this that seems to be the issue
       if(numericAverage[i] < 60) {
          gpa[i] = 'F';
       } else if(numericAverage[i] < 70) {
           gpa[i] = 'D';
       } else if(numericAverage[i] < 80) {
           gpa[i] = 'C';
       } else if(numericAverage[i] < 90) {
           gpa[i] = 'B';
       } else {
          gpa[i] = 'A';
       }
    }
          
  // Use nested for loops to read in the exam grades (the outside loop is your rows and inside loop is columns)
  // Inside the innermost loop, keep a running total of the student's grades
  // When the innermost loop completes, compute the average for that student and store it in the numericAverage array
  // Hint to compute average: 
  // numericAverage[i] = total / studentGrade[i].length; // i is the counter in the row loop
  // Use the numericAverage value to determine the letter grade and populate the gpa array 
  // Hint to compute letter grade: 
  // if (numericAverage[i] < 60)  // i is the counter in the row loop
    //     gpa[i] = 'F';
    // else if (numericAverage[i] < 70) 
    //     ...
    
  // Use nested for loops to iterate through the arrays and output array data
  // (notice the nested loop to output the exam grades stored in the 2-d array)
  
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(studentName[i] + " - Exam Grades:");
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
            System.out.print(" " + studentGrade[i][j]);
        System.out.println(", Average: " + numericAverage[i] + ", Letter Grade: " + gpa[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is here: `total = 0.0;`

You are setting the total outside the`for` loop, so it will count all grades from all students, so you should do it like this:

```
double total;
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
   total = 0.0;
   for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
       ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, right! I totally forgot I did that. Thank you so much! I couldn't for the life of me see what was wrong.

Comment: Needed a new pair of eyes, haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should reset your `total` variable back to 0 after each average calculation. Like this:

```
total = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
      studentGrade[i][j] = scnr.nextInt();
      total += studentGrade[i][j];
   }
   numericAverage[i] = total / studentGrade[i].length; //its something about this that seems to be the issue
   total = 0; //THIS!!
   if(numericAverage[i] < 60) {
      gpa[i] = 'F';
   } else if(numericAverage[i] < 70) {
      gpa[i] = 'D';
   } else if(numericAverage[i] < 80) {
      gpa[i] = 'C';
   } else if(numericAverage[i] < 90) {
      gpa[i] = 'B';
   } else {
      gpa[i] = 'A';
   }
}
```